# How to force Tor to use just one circuit?

Tags: configuration, circuit, protocol, research

We use Stem's `launch_tor_with_config` with the following config and then close all circuits opened by it (with `close_circuit`).

- `MaxCircuitDirtiness` and `NewCircuitPeriod`: tens of hours
- `MaxClientCircuitsPending`: 1

Then we build just one circuit by calling `new_circuit` (Stem) and set (`set_conf`) `__DisablePredictedCircuits` to 1 (since we cannot bootstrap with this setting).

After a while Tor starts building new circuits, which we don't want.

Most of the time we could find a sign of failure in the debug log just before the circuit creation, such as:

- `connection_ap_expire_beginning: "We tried for [10|15] seconds to
  connect to XX using exit XX Retrying on a new circuit"`
- `connection_ap_process_end_not_open(): Address XX refused due to 'misc
  error'. Considering retrying.`

How can we tell Tor to try really hard (longer timeouts, higher retry counts, ignore some connection failures etc.) before it opens a new circuit?

Comment: Why would you want to stop Tor from rotating circuits? What's your end goal with a setup like this?

Comment: @AndrewLott: Sorry for not mentioning the reason. This is for a website fingerprinting research project.

Answer (score 3):

Just looking through  [code on git](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/e6590efaa77c8cf186ce92e6ebad175e9c6450d1:/src/or/or.h)
 I'm seeing:

```
int NewCircuitPeriod; /**< How long do we use 
                    a circuit before building... **/
```

Which makes me think that if "10s of hours" in seconds is easily overflowing an int. try around 30000 maybe?

Comment: A signed int on a 32 bit machine can be a bit over 2.1 billion. That's the number of seconds in 68 years and a bit. (Of course it's possible that shorts are used internally, but not likely. Haven't looked.)